# How do I test child accounts? Test code shows nothing for child accounts ANSWERED

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, test-setup

How do I test child Accounts? The test I've written finds the parent account, but returns nothing from the child query.

Work: Display a button if the Account has a set of fields properly populated, OR the child Account has the fields populated.

Here's the code.

```
DisplayButton () {
String isVisible = 'false'
Id parentAccountId;

User currentUser = [ SELECT Id, ContactId, FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];

List<AccountContactRelation> accountContactRelationshipList = [ 
    SELECT Account.Id, 
    ***fields removed***
    FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE ContactId = :currentUser.ContactId
];
for (Integer i=0; i < accountContactRelationshipList.size(); i++){
    parentAccountList.add(accountContactRelationshipList[i].Account.ParentId);
        if(**** fields are correct ***){
            isVisible = 'true';
        }
        
}
if(ifVisible == 'false')
{
    List<Account> chidAccountQuery = [ 
    SELECT
    ***fields removed*** 
    FROM Account WHERE ParentId = :parentAccountId
    ];
  for (Integer i=0; i < childAccountQuery.size(); i++){
        if(**** fields are correct ***){
            isVisible = 'true';
        }
  }

}
return isVisible;
}
```

Here's the test

```
    Account parentAccount = createAccount('XYZ');
    Contact parentContact = createContact(parentAccount.Id);
    User parentUser = buildDummyUser('Customer');
    parentUser.ContactId = parentUser.Id;
    Account childAccount = createChildAccount('XYZ', parentAccount.Id);
    Contact childContact = createContact(childAccount.Id);
    User childUser = buildDummyUser('Customer');
    childUser.ContactId = childContact.Id;
    String result;
    System.runAs(currentUser){
        insert parentUser;
        insert childUser;
        

    }
    Test.startTest();
    System.runAs(parentUser) {
        result = BigButtonController.DisplayButton();
    }
```

I can share the setup code (Create User, Account, Contact) but it's really just setting properties and inserting the object.

*** EDIT ***
Here's the CreateAccount and CreateChildAccount code.

```
private static Account createAccount(String accType) {

    Account testAccount = TestUtilities.createAccount('Unit Test Account', true);
    testAccount.Type = accType;
  *** true fields are not populated ***
    update testAccount;
    return testAccount;
}   


private static Account createChildAccount(String accType, Id parentId) {
    Account testChildAccount = TestUtilities.createAccount('Unit Test Child Account', true);
    testChildAccount.Type = accType;
    testChildAccount.ParentId = parentId;
  *** true fields are populated***
    update testChildAccount;
    return testChildAccount;
}
```

***ANSWER***
What I ended up doing was putting all the data in the @TestSetup and then moving the childAccountQuery into it's own method, then testing that method.

```
public static void testChildVisible(){
    User parentUser = [Select Id, Contact.Account.Id from User where username = 'parentNoPerm@test.com'];
    
    List<Id> pAcctList = new LIst<Id>();
    pAcctList.add(parentUser.Contact.Account.Id);
    String result;
    Test.startTest();

        result = StatusIOController.getChildPermissions(pAcctList);
        
    Test.stopTest();
    System.debug(result);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, result, 'Result data should not be null');

    System.assertEquals('true', result, 'IsVisible is true');

}
```

Comment: Seeing `createChildAccount` is pretty crucial.

Comment: not clear from your testmethod whether your parentAccount/Contact do or do not set isVisible=true as if so, the childAccountQuery is never executed.